# Can we please let people know that there is a *general* winterbash tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms, winter-bash

Can we please stop creating new winterbash tags?

It seems that every year we will have a new one:

[winterbash-2012](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2012)[winterbash-2013](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2013)[winterbash-2014](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014)[winterbash-2015](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2015)[winterbash-2016](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2016)[winterbash-2017](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2017)[winterbash-2018](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2018)...

And **every** question that has to do with winterbash current *and* winterbash of the past will have to use all of the tags! [see my edit here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23269).

Can we please start using the general: [winterbash](/questions/tagged/winterbash) for all winterbash questions and *maybe* (not sure if a good idea or not) set the old winterbash tags as a synonym of this general one? **OR** Somehow let people know that if they tag with a **year specific** tag, that it should relate to that year and to to winterbash in general.

Comment: RoboCop wasn't born in 2012

Comment: Hmmm we need some way to tell people to tag **general** winterbash questions with the winterbash tag.

Comment: @qwertynl that is what retagging is for.  And SO has the same problem  (although in reverse) with general and version specific languages tags, and it seems to get along just fine

Comment: @psubsee2003 SO tagging is far from fine, which is one of the reasons I rarely use the site.

Answer (score 14):

It seems like there will be specific questions each year, as the hats and mechanisms change.  I think we need both the generic [winterbash](/questions/tagged/winterbash) and the year specific ones.  And yes, they will accumulate over time, but I think our system can handle it.

Answer (score 8):

But then how will we know which Winterbash we're talking about? 2012's and 2013's are *very* different, and 2014 will probably change a lot as well.

I don't see the problem here. There's nothing wrong with having a tag for every year; I doubt 10 more tags will crash the servers.

Answer (score 5):

I like the unique year tags for winterbash, and agree with the other points made about either using a generic or specific one.

I would also like to point out that if it were a large issue, these could always be synonym-ized and dealt with like many other tags in the past have been. Burnination could even be used if it were really that large of an issue.

As it stands now though, there is only 2012, and 2013, and I think it would be a little early to optimize for 2018.